# Stuck using PHP and Regex to prepare a DHCP output for MYSQL

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, dhcp

Hi I've been trying to no prevail to substitute certain elements using preg_replace and preg_match, basically I'm converting a dhcp lease output so I can insert the elements into a database.

I can do exactly what I need in notepad++ but I wanted to automate it using php here are my regex steps in notepad++:

Step 1)CODE

```
\s?-(\w)-\s?
\1~
```

Step 2)LEASE

```
-\s?(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d|NEVER EXPIRES|INACTIVE)\s?
~\1~
```

Step 3)ID the IP

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s+?-\s?(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
\1~\2
```

Step 4)ID the mac

```
 \s?-\s?(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){3,6}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}))
 ~\1
```

The desired output would be each element separated by a tilde symbol ~ ready to explode into an array that I can use in an insert statement:

```
192.25.200.4    ~ 255.255.255.192~ 64-9e-f3-b3-81-d3   ~01/08/2018 17:07:46    ~D~  BH1-WAP-01.local
```

Here is some test data:

```
Changed the current scope context to 192.25.200.0 scope.

Type : N - NONE, D - DHCP B - BOOTP, U - UNSPECIFIED, R - RESERVATION IP
============================================================================================
IP Address      - Subnet Mask    - Unique ID           - Lease Expires        -Type -Name   
============================================================================================

192.25.200.4    - 255.255.255.192- 64-9e-f3-b3-81-d3   -01/08/2018 17:07:46    -D-  BH1-WAP-01.local
192.25.200.5    - 255.255.255.192- 50-57-a8-30-11-f6   -01/08/2018 16:24:59    -D-  BH1-WAP-03.local
192.25.200.6    - 255.255.255.192- f0-f7-55-df-c4-ff   -01/08/2018 16:45:04    -D-  BH1-WAP-02.local
192.25.200.7    - 255.255.255.192- 00-23-24-bb-ce-83   -04/08/2018 10:55:00    -D-  CESTA1703043.LOCAL

No of Clients(version 4): 4 in the Scope : 192.25.200.0.

Command completed successfully.

Changed the current scope context to 192.25.200.64 scope.

Type : N - NONE, D - DHCP B - BOOTP, U - UNSPECIFIED, R - RESERVATION IP
============================================================================================
IP Address      - Subnet Mask    - Unique ID           - Lease Expires        -Type -Name   
============================================================================================

192.25.200.68   - 255.255.255.192- 28-94-0f-05-ac-6c   -01/08/2018 03:14:46    -D-  WAP-C12-01-1047.local

No of Clients(version 4): 1 in the Scope : 192.25.200.64.

Command completed successfully.
Changed the current scope context to 192.28.211.0 scope.
192.28.211.27   - 255.255.255.0  -00-0a-13-00-00-00-00- NEVER EXPIRES        -U-  CFCameraNearlockers

Changed the current scope context to 192.28.194.0 scope.
192.28.194.254  - 255.255.255.0  -00-48-32-95-85      - INACTIVE             -N-  bms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~^(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})\s*-\s*((?1))\s*-\s*((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){3,6}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})\s*-\s*(\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}\s\d\d(?::\d\d){2}|NEVER EXPIRES|INACTIVE)\s*-\s*(\w)\s*-\s*(.*)$~m'
```

and replace with

```
'$1 ~ $2 ~ $3 ~ $4 ~ $5 ~ $6'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SyH4Cl/1)

**Details**

- `^` -  start of a line
- `(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})` - Group 1: 1 to 3 digits, then 3 occurrences of `.` followed with 1 to 3 digits
- `\s*-\s*` - a `-` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `((?1))` - Group 2: capturing group 1 pattern
- `\s*-\s*` - a `-` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){3,6}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})` - Group 3: 3 to 6 occurrences of 2 hex chars followed with `:` or `-` and then 2 hex chars
- `\s*-\s*` - a `-` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}\s\d\d(?::\d\d){2}|NEVER EXPIRES|INACTIVE)` - Group 4: 2  digits, `/`, 2 digits, `/`, 4 digits, a whitespace, 2 digits and then 2 occurrences of `:` and 2  digits
- `\s*-\s*` - a `-` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(\w)` - Group 5: a word char
- `\s*-\s*` - a `-` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 6: the rest of the line
- `$` - end of a line.

If you need to only grab those lines and re-format, use

```
$text = <YOUR TEXT>;
$reg = '~^(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})\s*-\s*((?1))\s*-\s*((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){3,6}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})\s*-\s*(\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}\s\d\d(?::\d\d){2}|NEVER EXPIRES|INACTIVE)\s*-\s*(\w)\s*-\s*(.*)$~m';
$arr = [];
if (preg_match_all($reg, $text, $ms, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)) {
    foreach ($ms as $m) {
        $arr[] = $m[1] . ' ~ ' . $m[2] . ' ~ ' . $m[3] . ' ~ ' . $m[4] . ' ~ ' . $m[5] . ' ~ ' . $m[6];
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/NDusAA).

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 192.25.200.4 ~ 255.255.255.192 ~ 64-9e-f3-b3-81-d3 ~ 01/08/2018 17:07:46 ~ D ~ BH1-WAP-01.local
    [1] => 192.25.200.5 ~ 255.255.255.192 ~ 50-57-a8-30-11-f6 ~ 01/08/2018 16:24:59 ~ D ~ BH1-WAP-03.local
    [2] => 192.25.200.6 ~ 255.255.255.192 ~ f0-f7-55-df-c4-ff ~ 01/08/2018 16:45:04 ~ D ~ BH1-WAP-02.local
    [3] => 192.25.200.7 ~ 255.255.255.192 ~ 00-23-24-bb-ce-83 ~ 04/08/2018 10:55:00 ~ D ~ CESTA1703043.LOCAL
    [4] => 192.25.200.68 ~ 255.255.255.192 ~ 28-94-0f-05-ac-6c ~ 01/08/2018 03:14:46 ~ D ~ WAP-C12-01-1047.local
    [5] => 192.28.211.27 ~ 255.255.255.0 ~ 00-0a-13-00-00-00-00 ~ NEVER EXPIRES ~ U ~ CFCameraNearlockers
    [6] => 192.28.194.254 ~ 255.255.255.0 ~ 00-48-32-95-85 ~ INACTIVE ~ N ~ bms
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I just couldn't get my head round it but it is a lot clearer now.